# Where-Clause in LINQ Dictionary not working

Tags: c#, linq

I really can't work it out. I have a dictionary where I have saved an encoding table. I am trying now to get the correct value for the key.
The if-clause with those different where clauses should 100% lead to a result, but it doesnt. Are the where-clauses being ignored?

```
public static string ByteArrayToHex(byte[] bytes)
    {            
            StringBuilder Result = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);
            string HexAlphabet = "0123456789ABCDEF";

            foreach (byte B in bytes)
            {
                Result.Append(HexAlphabet[(int)(B >> 4)]);
                Result.Append(HexAlphabet[(int)(B & 0xF)]);
            }

            return Result.ToString();

    }


static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<byte> byteList2 = new List<byte>() { 227, 129,130 };

        List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>() {131, 95, 131, 126, 129, 91};
        string filename = "file.txt";
        var dict = Shared.IO.Read.EncodingTable(filename);

        var original = Encoding.GetEncoding(932).GetString( byteList.ToArray());
        var custom = CustomConverter(byteList, dict);

        var original2 = Encoding.GetEncoding(932).GetString(byteList2.ToArray());
        var custom2 = CustomConverter(byteList2, dict);

        Console.WriteLine("Original: " + original);
        Console.WriteLine("Custom: " + custom);
        Console.WriteLine("Original: " + original2);
        Console.WriteLine("Custom: " + custom2);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static string CustomConverter(List<byte> byteList, Dictionary<string,string> dict)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;

        while (byteList.Count != 0)
        {
            var count = byteList.Count;

            byte[] bytes = new byte[] { };
            if (count > 2) bytes = new byte[3] {byteList[0], byteList[1], byteList[2]};
            if (count == 2) bytes = new byte[2] {byteList[0], byteList[1]};
            if (count == 1) bytes = new byte[1] {byteList[0]};

            var hexString = Shared.IO.Convert.ByteArrayToHex(bytes);
            KeyValuePair<string,string> entry;



            if (hexString.Length > 2)
            {
                var a = hexString.Substring(0, 4);
                var b = hexString.Substring(0, 2);
                var c = hexString.Substring(0, 1);

                entry = (from item in dict
                    where item.Key == hexString || item.Key == a || item.Key == b || item.Key == c
                    select item).First();
            }

            else
            {
                var a = hexString.Substring(0, 1);

                entry = (from item in dict
                where item.Key == hexString || item.Key == a
                select item).First();
            }
            byteList.RemoveRange(0, (entry.Key.Length / 2));

            result = result + entry.Value;
        }

        return result;
}`

public static Dictionary<string, string> EncodingTable(string filename)
    {
        string directory = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\encoding\";
        string path = directory + filename;

        Dictionary<string,string> encodingTable = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;
            if (line.StartsWith("#")) continue;

            var lineArray = line.Split(';');
            encodingTable.Add(lineArray[0], lineArray[1]);
        }

        return encodingTable;
    }`
```

The dictionary contains things like this

79;か
7A;き
7B;く
7C;け
7D;こ
7E;さ
7F;し
80;す
81;せ
82;そ
83;た
84;ち

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We need to see the keys you have in that dictionary as well as which bytes you try to match against. Also, post what `ByteArrayToHex` returns.

Comment: Can you update your code sample with something that we can use to reproduce your result? As it is, we don't know what the value of `hexString` is, or what the dictionary contains. A short method that populates the dictionary would be helpful.

Comment: What does `ByteArrayToHex` return?  I assume it's a string because of the `Substring` call but then you call `Substring(0,1)` if the length is greater than 2. Have you inspected the values of `a`, `b`, `c` in the debugger to make sure they are what you expect them to be?

Comment: I'm not seeing any obvious errors. Without sample data it's hard to know what's going wrong.

Comment: You need to replace `dict` and `byteList` with mocked examples so that they can be tested and verified. As it stands, this is going to be very hard for anyone to answer, and as indicated by the comments here, users would like to help. Please edit.

Comment: As a side note, doing 4 key lookups (stopping when you have a match) would likely be faster then iterating through the keys looking for one that matches any of 4 possible values.

Comment: Thanks for the fast comments. I updated the code. Could you give me a sample for that or a link? @D Stanley?

Comment: What is this `Shared.IO.Read.EncodingTable`? It would be good to see how and what is getting put in your dictionary. The keys may not be the values you expect.

Comment: Updated again. It does work with the byteList, but not with byteList2.

Comment: hatchet is right. I took the dictionary and checked all the values. It was not from me, so i wasnt sure.
I also used now dict.TryGetValue and if its true, i start querying. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Insight - Just as a side-note - you can replace your `string ByteArrayToHex(byte[] bytes)` with `BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "")` or `String.Join("", bytes.Select(x => String.Format("{0:X2}", x)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code, and creating a file.txt with the data you provided suplemented with

`5F;_
5B;[
E1;#
E3;#`

I get the response:

```
Original: ダミー
Custom: た _た さ せ [
Original: 縺・
Custom: #せ そ
```

Are you seeing something different?  Or is this not what you want?

Comment: Yeah, it does look correct (without the whole dictionary knowing).

My result is

HEX: 835F837E815B
Original: ダミー
Custom: たeたさせa
HEX: E38182
Original: 縺・
Custom: せそ
HEX: 5F5BE1E3
Original: 膺AQ7
Custom: ?GOq

I have used another solution. dict.TryGetValue and if its true, I start the query.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have tried different things, the TryGetValue method is the best choice than using too many where-conditions. Even though the performance was really bad. Thanks for the hint "D Stanley".

The goal is to check in a dictionary (size = max 3 bytes) if my current array (converted to a hexstring) is in this dictionary. If that is the case, it shall return the output value. Hopefully someone finds it useful.

```
    private static string _hexString = null;
    public static string ByteValueToCustomEncoding(byte[] byteArray, Dictionary<string, string> dict)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;

        _hexString = Shared.IO.Convert.ByteArrayToHex(byteArray);

        while (_hexString.Length > 0)
        {
            string entry = string.Empty;

            if (_hexString.Length >= 6)
            {
                entry = Helper(dict);
            }

            else if (_hexString.Length >= 4)
            {
                entry = Helper(dict);
            }

            else if (_hexString.Length >= 2)
            {
                entry = Helper(dict);
            }

            else if (_hexString.Length >= 1)
            {
                entry = Helper(dict);
            }

            result = result + entry;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static string Helper(Dictionary<string,string> dict)
    {
        string temp = String.Empty;

        for (int i = (_hexString.Length > 6) ? 6: _hexString.Length; i >= 0; i = i - 2)
        {
            if (dict.TryGetValue(_hexString.Substring(0, (i == 0) ? 1 : i), out temp))
            {
                _hexString = _hexString.Remove(0, i);
                return temp;
            }
        }

        _hexString = _hexString.Remove(0, 1);

        return temp;
    }
```